# Designing a Cosmos partition key for a single container which handles nightly large queries and large data

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I currently have five Cosmos DB containers which each contain ~800K documents (and growing). The document sizes vary wildly with a range from 1-40KB. The database has very low user usage, maybe 200-500 lookups a day using id + primary key. The partition key design of each container is essentially a modulus of the id to 100 logical partitions.

The reason I don't use id as the partition key is because there are a few cross-partition queries. Specifically, one container has about 100 lookups a day using a field for which the partition key is not known. Also, one container is indexed hourly by Azure Search which looks for all changed documents using _ts. Also, three containers take part it a nightly process (at separate times) by which every single (partial) document is downloaded into an ingestion process of a completely separate system of which changes can be discovered and updated back into the container.

Summary of the current container layout:

```
Container 1
- About 800K documents and partition key is 100 modulus of id
- About 200-500 lookups a day using id + partition key
- About 100 lookups a day using a field for which partition key is unknown
- Indexed hourly by Azure Search
- Nightly every partial document is downloaded and potentially upserted
```

```
Container 2
- About 800K documents and partition key is 100 modulus of id
- About 200-500 lookups a day using id + partition key
- Nightly every partial document is downloaded and potentially upserted
```

```
Container 3
- About 800K documents and partition key is 100 modulus of id
- About 200-500 lookups a day using id + partition key
- Nightly every partial document is downloaded and potentially upserted
```

```
Container 4
- About 800K documents and partition key is 100 modulus of id
- About 200-500 lookups a day using id + partition key
```

```
Container 5
- About 100K documents and partition key is 100 modulus of id
- About 200-500 lookups a day using id + partition key
```

The multi-container design I have now works great. However, given the low user usage, the cost is too high and so I want to consolidate the five containers into one. If I merge the five containers into one, the question is how do I design a new partitioning scheme which continues to allow fast lookup, but also the queries don't take a massive amount of time and RUs.

My main concern is I want to make sure my large queries only focus on the partitions containing the documents of concern. Each existing container is already distributed to 100 logical partitions and since the existing query is container-wide (it gets all documents) I didn't need to worry about the fan-out. But now if all containers are merged I want the queries to target just the partitions I care about so the scans are not touching the partitions I am not interested in. The only options I have thought of so far are:

```
1) Keep the existing 100 logical partition design per "container" (namespace
   of documents) and have the queries use "IN" to target all 100 partitions.
- Unfortunately range like STARTSWITH on partition key will not prevent fan-out.
- Having so many partition keys in an "IN" clause may make the query very
  long and I don't know of the consequences of that. In my test it seems to work
  fine -- the query length just adds about 10 to 20 RUs onto the query.
- If there are no problems with large queries, this probably would just work
  fine and keep good performance.
```

```
2) Have one logical partition per "container" (namespace of documents).
- Because of low usage performance is probably still acceptable.
- May exceed permitted document size per-container.
```

```
3) Have two-ten logical partitions and have the queries use "IN"
- This makes the "IN" usage of #1 more palettable.
- Won't have the look-up performance of #1, but better than #2.
- Logical containers are still very large.
```

```
4) Just deal with the fan out and having high-RU queries.
- Database may be unusable at some points during the night.
- The Azure Search _ts-based queries don't seem to have much impact on the
  performance.
```

I am leaning to do #1, but I am hoping somebody has feedback for me before I move forward with a design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple hours after I asked this question I discovered a new Cosmos DB feature which [allows all containers within a database to share throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#set-throughput-on-a-database). This solves all of my concerns.